# How to let Emacs display a different character from that actually stored?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I want to implement dynamical text replacement (only the display is replaced, the actual stored file is not replaced) for Emacs, using Elisp.

For example, in LaTeX documents, I want to type `\alpha`, and let Emacs display it just as `α`, so it is easier to read. But in the result `.tex` file, I still want `\alpha`, instead of `α` to be saved. (Remark: I could use XeTeX or LuaTeX myself to support UTF-8 directly. But for the reason of collaboration and journal requirements, I don't want the UTF-8 characters to be directly saved in the `.tex` files. Alternatively I could use preview in AUCTeX. But that doesn't help when I am editing the formula)

An existing example is in org-mode, when we type `[[link][name]]`, right after typing the last `]`, the displayed text is replaced by just the name, with hyperlink. On the other hand, when saving this file, the saved content is the original `[[link][name]]`, different from the displayed one.

Any ideas how this could be implemented?

PS: The [Display Specs That Replace The Text](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Replacing-Specs.html#Replacing-Specs) section of Emacs manual goes close. However, I need to specify the start and end points, instead of the desired string for the replacements. This means I need to do search after every user input to decide the start and end points. This looks unrealistic due to performance and complexity of algorithm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to do this is to add font lock keywords for the relevant modes, and to use `compose-region` to display the new glyph in place of the old string:

```
(font-lock-add-keywords
 'latex-mode `(("\\(\\\\alpha\\)"
                (0 (progn (compose-region (match-beginning 1)
                                          (match-end 1) "α")
                          nil)))))
```

---

Please also note that `org-mode` has a feature of this kind already built-in, not only for links as you mentioned, but also for LaTeX-like entities:

```
(setq org-pretty-entities t)
```

Comment: `compose-region` seems to only work when the display result should be a single character. So e.g. if I pass `"bar"` as the result-string parameter, `compose-region` collapses all 3 letters to a single one. IOW, passing a `"α"` and `"ααα"` both will get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

The @FrançoisFévotte's answer come pretty close, except that `compose-region` is not an appropriate function for the task. This function collapses the "display string" to a single character, which is likely not what you wanted. IOW, if instead of passing `"α"` you decide passing a `"ααα"` you'll still get a single `α` character as result.

Instead you want a `put-text-property` function. So for example:

```lisp
(font-lock-add-keywords
 'latex-mode `(("\\(\\\\alpha\\)"
                (0 (progn (put-text-property (match-beginning 1) (match-end 1)
                                             'display "α")
                           nil)))))
```