# Emacs Abbreviations for Display Only

Tags: emacs

I'm editing Mathematica code in emacs.  Mathematica's plaintext representation for greek letters looks like

```
\[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Gamma], ...
```

I don't mind typing these out, but the resulting code is big and clunky-looking, e.g.:

```
k[\[Beta]_,z_]:=z^(\[Beta]/2) Hypergeometric2F1[\[Beta]/2,\[Beta]/2,\[Beta],z];
```

Is there some way to make emacs automatically display certain strings (like `\[Alpha]`) as other strings (like the unicode character for alpha)?  Note, I don't want to actually replace one string with another (which is what abbreviation does, if I understand correctly), since the file should still be readable correctly by Mathematica.

Comment: The way other modes (say, org-mode) do this is with invisibility specs.  Might be a bit of a project to implement, but check out http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Invisible-Text.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to let Emacs display a different character from that actually stored?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13600160/how-to-let-emacs-display-a-different-character-from-that-actually-stored)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there's a way. Plain Emacs solution is to use `compose-region` function that does exactly that. This snippet will define you a function `compose-greek-symbols` which will activate the requested abbreviation replacement in current buffer if font-lock is active:

```lisp
(setq
 greek-symbols
 (loop
  ;; characters are entered with `ucs-insert'
  ;; 'α' is "GREEK SMALL LETTER ALPHA"
  for ch from ?α to ?ω
  collect (let ((str (get-char-code-property ch 'name)))
        (setq str
          (upcase-initials
           (downcase
            (replace-regexp-in-string "greek small letter " "" str))))
        (cons str ch))))


(defun compose-greek-symbols ()
  (interactive)
  (font-lock-add-keywords
   nil
   '(("\\\\\\[\\([^]]+\\)\\]"
      (0 (progn (let
            ((sym (cdr-safe (assoc (match-string 1) greek-symbols))))
          (when sym
            (compose-region (match-beginning 0)
                    (match-end 0)
                    sym)))))))))
```

EmacsWiki offers couple [more solutions](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PrettySymbol). And if you're open to installing new packages, you can always try something more sophisticated, like [pretty-symbols-mode](https://github.com/drothlis/pretty-symbols).